# Вопрос по Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, парсер, dom

Доброго времени суток.
Собственно в чем проблема, элементы я с горем пополам получаю. 
Но наблюдается некая тенденция, что во время загрузки я могу получить элемент а могу и не получить, кто знает в чем может быть проблема? Пробовал и на хостинге и на локалке и на VPS, грешил что ресурса мало, оказалось не в этом дело.

Буду премного благодарен за помощь.

П.С.
Вот [ссылка](http://www.aromastore.com.ua/koleso2000/parser.php) где запущен скрипт, если пару раз "поклацать" обновление страницы, то проблему Вы увидите. Ниже прилагаю "код".

```
<?php 
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('https://koleso2000.ua/shina/zimnyaya/michelin-alpin-a5/195-65r15-91-t-neship');

sleep(5);

if(count($html->find("/html",0)))
    {
        foreach($html->find('div.in-top p') as $model) {echo ''.$model.'';} echo '<br>';
        foreach($html->find('div.second p a',1) as $brand) {$brand = $brand->plaintext; echo ''.$brand.'';} echo '<br>';
        foreach($html->find('h1') as $name) {$name = $name->innertext;} echo '<br>';
        echo $name;
    }
else
    {
        echo "Объект не загружен!";
    }

$html->clear();
unset($html);   
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скорее всего проблема в том что некоторые данные подгружаются аяксом(серединка).  Попробуйте использовать таймаут.

Comment: **sleep(10);** -  добавил после загрузки файлы _(на 4-ой строке)_, проблема осталась (

Comment: Интересно, сложно выделить участок кода скопировать и вставить? или вы думаете человек будет разбираться в скриншоте а потом печатать текст для ответа? скопируйте код.

Comment: @RomanPolshikov и еще наблюдал, допустим если сразу выводить полученное по ссылке содержимое. То зачастую я вижу не весь сайт, а только куски, ощущение что не успел подгрузиться. И после обновления страницы сайт может полностью загрузиться, а может только шапка.

Comment: @Naumov - я откровенно говоря пытался, но у меня почему то в черновике не весь код отображался

Comment: Выделите код в редакторе и  на кнопку `{ }`  нажмите она отфарматирует его.

Comment: @naumov Спасибо что отредактировал, впредь буду знать )

Comment: `plaintext` на `innertext` попробуй заменить и циклы разверни как надо построчно, а не на одной строке. И сделай `var_dump` элементов цикла что там есть вообще?

Comment: @Naumov данное решение не помогло, все равно проблема остается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перепишите запрос HTML используя curl, при необходимости добавите таймаут в пару секунд

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://koleso2000.ua/shina/zimnyaya/michelin-alpin-a5/195-65r15-91-t-neship');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, только в 3-ей строке еще необходимо было ";" поставить =) Если не сильно часто обращаться к серверу, то все ок, ну думаю данную проблему можно решить таймаутом, как Вы и написали =)